# Xmlhttp CROSS request through Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I am sending a ajax request to duckduckgo api to fetch detail related to a object my code is

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'http://api.duckduckgo.com/',
      crossDomain: true,
      data: 'q=iphone&format=json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(results){
        console.log(results);
        }

});
```

and responce i am reciving in console is

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=iphone&format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access
```

I know this is issue because I am sending request to a cross domain . and the solution is editing conf file on server .
but here in case i don't have server access nor i am writing php code is there any way of handling this through Jquery only .

I try setting crossdomain parameter : true ..

Still not working

Comment: Sorry, the only ways to solve this problem is to modify the server returning the data to properly return CORS headers, return JSONP format data, or to create a proxy on your local server to retrieve the data using your favorite server-side language rather than client-side javascript. the `crossDomain` parameter is irrelevant for cross-domain requests unless for some reason you wanted to treat it as a non-crossdomain request (which doesn't make sense)

Comment: @KevinB : thank you but how can i modify data return by Server

Comment: you can't modify it without doing what you specified you didn't want to do.

Comment: @KevinB : ohh thnq got it ;)